# Opening ArcGIS Pro application from ArcGIS Pro Project (.aprx) file using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I need to open an ArcGIS Pro project (.aprx) file in the ArcGIS Pro application inside of an arcpy script.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

I am using ArcGIS pro 2.4.1.

By open, I mean having the application actually open up on my screen. Similar to opening it from the start menu but utilizing the script instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similar to open PDF files in Adobe Acrobat Reader in the past so I just looked up this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/104254/115) to [Opening PDF generated by Python AddIn using Report (*.rlf) file automatcally?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104246) and tested:

```
import os
myfile = r"C:\Temp\Projects\TestProject\TestProject.aprx"
os.system("start " + myfile)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\path\to\project.aprx")
```

For further things you can do with `aprx` refer to the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm).

Comment: I meant open as in have it pop up, as if the icon was double clicked. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use subprocess to do this. In my implementation, subprocess was a better choice.

```
import subprocess
myfile = r"C:\Temp\Projects\TestProject\TestProject.aprx"
subprocess.Popen([myfile], shell=True)
```